# c# calculating portfolio beta between stock and index

Tags: c#, statistics, beta, coefficients

does anyone know a way to calculate Beta (beta coefficient) for a portfolio or stock vs. a benchmark, such as an index like S&P in c#?

I already have 2 arrays of type double that would be required for such a calculation but I can't find any sleek way to do this.

StatisticFormula.BetaFunction Method (Double, Double) exists but this accepts one value for each param, not an array - which statistically makes no sense.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what the values in each array represent? E.g. you have one array of closing prices for a stock, and one array of closing prices for a particular market?

Comment: Yes, sorry to leave that out, I have two arrays of daily returns.   To get there i have arrays of closing prices and previous closes' prices, one for a portfolio and one for the market, however the beta calculation most likely requires the returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any good C# Finance/Statistics packages, so I wrote the method directly and borrowed from this stats package: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42492/Using-LINQ-to-Calculate-Basic-Statistics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] closingPriceStock = { 39.32, 39.45, 39.27, 38.73, 37.99, 38.38, 39.53, 40.55, 40.78, 41.3, 41.35, 41.25, 41.1, 41.26, 41.48, 41.68, 41.77, 41.92, 42.12, 41.85, 41.54 };
            double[] closingPriceMarket = { 1972.18, 1988.87, 1987.66, 1940.51, 1867.61, 1893.21, 1970.89, 2035.73, 2079.61, 2096.92, 2102.44, 2091.54, 2083.39, 2086.05, 2084.07, 2104.18, 2077.57, 2083.56, 2099.84, 2093.32, 2098.04 };

            double[] closingPriceStockDailyChange = new double[closingPriceStock.Length - 1];
            double[] closingPriceMarketDailyChange = new double[closingPriceMarket.Length - 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < closingPriceStockDailyChange.Length; i++)
            {
                closingPriceStockDailyChange[i] = (closingPriceStock[i + 1] - closingPriceStock[i]) * 100 / closingPriceStock[i];
                closingPriceMarketDailyChange[i] = (closingPriceMarket[i + 1] - closingPriceMarket[i]) * 100 / closingPriceMarket[i];
            }

            double beta = Covariance(closingPriceStockDailyChange, closingPriceMarketDailyChange) / Variance(closingPriceMarketDailyChange);

            Console.WriteLine(beta);

            Console.Read();
        }


        public static double Variance(this IEnumerable<double> source)
        {
            int n = 0;
            double mean = 0;
            double M2 = 0;

            foreach (double x in source)
            {
                n = n + 1;
                double delta = x - mean;
                mean = mean + delta / n;
                M2 += delta * (x - mean);
            }
            return M2 / (n - 1);
        }

        public static double Covariance(this IEnumerable<double> source, IEnumerable<double> other)
        {
            int len = source.Count();

            double avgSource = source.Average();
            double avgOther = other.Average();
            double covariance = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                covariance += (source.ElementAt(i) - avgSource) * (other.ElementAt(i) - avgOther);

            return covariance / len;
        }

    }


}
```

This would have to be refactored to calculate beta in a function, you can import the linked package to avoid the static methods I included, etc., but this is just a toy example.

Comment: Thank you for this...it looks like the way I will have to go.  So surprising, given c#'s lean towards business dev that this doesn't exist.